# My favorite animal is a - singular and plural form

Tags: singular-vs-plural

- > My favorite animal is a dog (or the dog).
- > My favorite animal is a horse (or the horse).

Both are correct, aren't they? But what if both animals are your favorites? How do we say it?

Is it correct to say: my favorite animals are *a dog* and *a horse*. Or rather: my favorite animals are *dogs* and *horses*.
In which case, why do we put the animals in their plural form, i.e dogs and horses?

What is the difference, i.e. technical grammar explanation to this?

Comment: You can say ' my favourite animals are the dog and the horse'.

Comment: Do you mean to talk about a species in genreral, or a singular member of a species?

Comment: My favorite animals are dogs and horses. General statements in English use the plural form, very often: Apples are good for you. Motorcycles can be dangerous.

Comment: How contrary is this? If your favourite animal is ***a*** dog that can mean a particular individual, despite the indefinite article. Conversely ***the*** dog would be any dog - generic.

Comment: To answer 'why put the dogs and horses in plural form?' To match the plurality of 'animals'.  While JamesK is correct, using 'my favourite x is a y' isn't unheard of in native speakers.  Also idiomatic is: 'my favourite animals are dogs'. Very technically - and possibly why you haven't encountered it before - 'favourite' arguably should apply to only one.  It's strictest meaning is 'the *most* liked', or 'liked above *all* others'.

Answer (score 19):

"My favourite animal is a dog" seems to refer to one single dog. "... his name is Scruffy".

If you mean you like dogs more than other animals you might use the "generic the"

> My favourite animal is the dog.

However, that's rather formal. You'd actually probably be better to use the plural, and make "Dogs" the subject

> Dogs are my favourite animals.

We can use plurals to speak in general about a "type of animal".

And so if you want to mention two types of animal:

> Dogs and horses are my favourite animals.

Comment: +1 for rephrasing with "Dogs" as the subject

Comment: re: *My favorite animal is the dog.*  This could also have a different meaning depending on context.  e.g.: If you live in a house with a dog, a cat and a hamster, and you prefer the dog over the other two, for example.  Or maybe you're referring to characters in a kid's movie. "*My favorite animal is the dog.  He had the best jokes.*"

Comment: Lots of people say "My favourite animal is a dog" meaning dogs in general.

Comment: Informally I would also expect to hear *My favourite animal is dogs* – I would disagree with @DJClayworth that '...is a dog' is at all natural unless a specific dog is meant.

Comment: @dbmag9 - Subject/verb agreement. Not *animal is dogs* but *animals are dogs* - *My favorite animals are dogs.*

Comment: @Chuck *My favourite meal is eggs, my favourite band is the Beatles, my favourite weather is thunder and lightning*. The subject of the sentence is 'my favourite animal' which makes the verb singular. The other way around, 'Dogs are my favourite animal' has 'are' because the subject is now plural.

Comment: @dbmag9 fair enough! :D

Answer (score 4):

When you say

> My favorite animal is a dog

you are stating that some specific dog is your favorite animal.

When you say

> My favorite animal is the dog

you are stating that you favor dogs in general over any other **type** of animal. You could just as well say

> My favorite type of animal is the dog.

Now, particularly in speech, not everyone will be careful about the use of the indefinite article, but when the the definite article is used, the intent is almost always to indicate a type or class.

There is no theoretical difference if “animal” is replaced by “animals.” However, it is less likely, at least in American speech, that the definite article will be used to distinguish between specific exemplars and general types. If a native speaker of American English wants to talk about mulriple types, they will far more often say

> My favorite types of animal are dogs and horses

than

> My favorite animals are the dog and the horse.

In fact, I venture the opinion that the second formulation will sound stilted to American ears.

Comment: Speaking as a native AmE speaker, "My favorite types of animal are dogs and horses" sounds unnatural and stilted to me. I would word it rather as "Dogs and horses are my favorite animals".

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use 'Dogs and horses are my favourite animals'.

We can also say 'The dog and the horse are my favourite animals'.

'My favourite animal is a dog and a horse' means a specific dog and a specific horse.

['My favourite animals are dogs and horses' and 'My favourite animals are the dog and the horse' are grammatically correct.]